# How can I apply text shadow with a stroke using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to style this text exactly similar to attached image, tried using text-shadow but not get exact similar results. I want to add a border on shadowed text. Please provide a better a solution!

Thanks

[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.stroke-shadow {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: -7px -7px 0px #FF29ED;
}

p {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 200px;
}
```

```html
<p class="stroke-shadow">CREATE</p>
```

Comment: _"and m able to done this with absolute relative with two different p tags but getting problem in responsiveness"_ - if you show us what you got, perhaps we could help you with the responsiveness issue ...

Comment: @CBroe it was not a good solution even it also not solve the problem, I want to do this only from css...

Comment: what about `-webkit-text-stroke`: https://caniuse.com/?search=text-stroke . however, text-stroke cannot be moved relative to the parent element. So doing that effect only with CSS and this doesn't look like it's doable.

Comment: @CornelRaiu I want to add border stroke only on the shadowed text

Comment: I'm personally disappointed that I can't get this to work: https://jsfiddle.net/r2h4L3fv/; if only `drop-shadow()` had a "spread" parameter, as `box-shadow()` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution for CSS only is to use the `:before` pseudo element. However, this would require adding the specific string in the content rule.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.stroke-shadow {
  color: white;

  position: relative
}

.stroke-shadow:before {
  content: "CREATE";
  color: black;
  
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #FF29ED;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
}


p {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 200px;
}
```

```html
<p class="stroke-shadow">CREATE</p>
```

Comment: This is probably the only pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a pseudo-element and [text-stroke](https://caniuse.com/?search=text-stroke). By using a data attribute you can keep your content out of your CSS. You could also easily generate the attribute with JavaScript based on text content if you prefer.

```js
// As an alternative to manually implementing data attributes...
document.querySelectorAll('.stroke-shadow').forEach(el => {
  el.setAttribute('data-othertext', el.textContent);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

p {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 200px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.stroke-shadow {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.stroke-shadow::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: -12px;
  width: 100%;
  top: -12px;
  height: 100%;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px #FF29ED;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<p class="stroke-shadow" data-text="CRE">CRE</p>
```

Comment: if the OP is able to edit the HTML or add some JS, then the `attr(data-text)` is definitely cleaner than hardcoding the value in the `content` as I did in my answer.